# 14 - 7 = 3: Arithmetic overflow in Careers invitation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I recently was invited to create a Careers profile (I'm flattered, by the way).

On Monday, the 29<sup>th</sup> of October, I received the invitation, saying

> [snip flattering stuff about my contributions and Careers] But please act soon: this invitation expires in **14 days**, ...

(Emphasis is mine.)

I didn't act swiftly, so today, Monday the 5<sup>th</sup> of November [Remember, remember ...] I received the following reminder:

> We noticed you have not accepted our [invitation](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) to join Stack Overflow Careers.  **Only 3 days remain** before it expires, and we’d love to have you.

(Emphasis is mine again.)

Thank you for the flowers, and I acted before Careers decided that maybe `3 - 1 = 0`, but somebody should take a look at the code for calculating how many days the invitation remains standing.

Comment: *Thank you for the flowers, and I acted before Careers decided that maybe `3 - 1 = 0`* -- Mission. Accomplished.

Comment: @animuson They'd have gotten me sooner if they said it lasts only five days from the get-go.

Comment: Thanks, @Pop, here on meta, my spelling checker checks for Portuguese spelling today, so basically everything had squiggly red lines.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for the report Daniel. Invites should definitely be good for 14 days, but our invitation code was creating them with 10 day expirations for some reason. The first invitation e-mail text has 14 hard coded in it, so that was still right. However, the follow-up e-mail actually calculates the days remaining on the invitation, so it was using the 10 day expiration we store in the database.

Sorry for the bug. You won't ever get to see it work correctly :( but it has been fixed.

Comment: "You won't ever get to see it work correctly :(" Hah, I'm going to create sock puppets just to check whether it's really fixed.