# Unable to log to careers 2.0 - stuck at login?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I have received some days ago a notification of an invite to join the Careers 2.0 site. The invitation referred to a previous invite, which I never found (starting to believe it was swallowed in the mail filters).

Since then I have tried some times to log to the site and accept the invitation... but I wasn't able to make it work. I would click the create profile link, enter the login info on the next page and then... nothing. The system would just sit there, with the log-in prompt still shown in the site header (no name shown, so you appear as log-off) but any new attempt to log won't display the login&password fields anymore - they reappear only if I clear all browser cookies.

Any idea why this is happening? Based on the mail date, I believe that the invitation may have timed-out, but it wouldn't work even last saturday (although that may depend on some network problem on my side during the weekend)... Any hope to have the invitation renewed so that I may try again to create that account?

---

**EDIT**:
Seems to be similar to the problem described in this post: [Cannot accept invitation to Stack Overflow Careers 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154730/cannot-accept-invitation-to-stack-overflow-careers-2-0)

---

**EDIT 2**: About the login problems

I followed Jason advice and cleared the cookies, then tried to log on the careers site, but the problem didn't go away. 
That said, I noticed something strange: the first login prompt after clearing the cookies displayed the "log with open id" panel on the right, but any following attempt displayed it on the LEFT. After that, clicking the "login with stack exchange" option would just log me for that single postback - any other link I follow will then redisplay the standart logged out interface. Also, I went to log on meta soon after and as usual I wasn't prompted to retype the credential (just like when you first log on a site in the stackexchange family and you are already logged on another site), so the cookie must be there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about that SP, and thanks for the report. Between last night and this morning we suffered a bug related to our login cookies *and* a bug related to our invitation code, both of which you were a victim of.

They've both been fixed and you should be able to accept your invitation now. Again, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you Jason, seem it worked this time. Now I have some problems related to the login (which seems to be randomly lost while I surf the site, yet must always be here since a second login attempt does NOT redisplay the user/pass prompt).

Comment: Other notice: the user is there, when I log I can see the username in the header section. It's just that the system seem to randomly think I still need to log-in while the cookie is still there. Maybe this is the login cookie bug you where talking about? Will see if I find anything related in the meta discussions.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: Hmm. Try clearing your cookies for careers and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried just now. It didn't help. But I noticed something strange: first login prompt displayed the "log with open id" panel on the right, then any other attempt displayed it on the LEFT. Again, clicking the "login with stack exchange" option would just log me for that single postback - any other link I follow will then redisplay the standart logged out interface. Also, I went to log on meta soon after and as usual I wasn't prompted to retype the credential (just like when you first log on a site in the stackexchange family and you are already logged on another site), so the cookie must be there

Comment: any idea what could cause this? Will try to see if something change after clearing (again) the cookies. I will add here anything new that I may notice

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: The left/right thing is correct behavior (we show you the first thing you've used before). We're still unsure about the lost login stuff.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your message. Tested with IE and Firefox. Was going to try with Chrome... but as now it seems to be working so I will try to not disturb the sleeping dog...