# Is there a problem with login on careers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, login

Login sequence goes OK, no errors. When I click any link or refresh a page, the session is lost.

I'm using my livejournal openID account and opera browser. IE9 does the same.

Comment: Just checked, happening for me too.

Comment: Same here in Chrome.

Comment: Everything is OK here. using Chrome and a Google Account.

Comment: At least a day, maybe two seeing this

Comment: just checked, everything is fine. used google chrome.

Comment: Here it's consistent, I'm able to reproduce it in 100% cases.

Comment: Seems exactly what I am experiencing here ([link to my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154768/unable-to-log-to-careers-2-0-stuck-at-login/154803#comment445458_154803)). Can anyone confirm if the behaviour is the same?

Comment: OK I've got a repro here on a fresh install of Opera.

Comment: Same issue, IE9, Facebook login.  Has been happening for about 4 days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior should be fixed now in IE9 and Opera. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I got repros for this behavior in IE9 and Opera only. I didn't see the behavior on Firefox or Chrome, but if you were experiencing it I'm guessing that's fixed now too. It seems that Opera and IE9 have different policies from Firefox and Chrome when it comes to leading-dot/no-dot domains on cookies.

Comment: Seems fixed now, thanks.

Comment: @Soonts: No problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are some browser issues related to login session. After trying Opera even cache clearance didn't solve problem.

But using chrome after clearing cache login process flows as normal.

So I advice using chrome and clear cookie history (at least for Stack Overflow)