# Error accepting careers.stackoverflow.com invitation

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, email

I clicked on the invite in my email, 8 days after getting it, within the 14 it says are needed. I looked at [Cannot accept invitation to Stack Overflow Careers 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154730/cannot-accept-invitation-to-stack-overflow-careers-2-0) but that seems to be for some issues a long time back.

Comment: Please post the exact error you got.

Answer (score 4):

Oops, I totally broke this while cleaning up some old code. Sorry about that - thanks for letting us know.

I have now pushed a fix so please try again.